# What statistical method should be use if I have a 1 x n matrix of data

Tags: chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I am doing some data analysis on medical data and need to know what the most appropriate statistical method to use would. the data will be for a particular disease and checking against patients HIV status. example:

[image]

Since this is a 1 x 3 matrix, I cannot calculate using Chi Square since the expected will equal the observed hence resulting in a p = 0.

Please advise on the most appropriate method to use

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What question(s) do you have about the data? For instance,  what do you want to know that is not conveyed by the chart you posted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know whether it is required to show that based on the results that there is a statistical significance the having the disease is linked to being HIV positive.

Comment: How could you conclude that without a non-diseased group? For instance, if non-diseased people had the same 60/20/5 split, would this disease really be a predictor of HIV? What if the non-diseased group was 75/5/5?

Comment: Thanks Dave. The interest is not necessarily on checking the non-diseased group. This is a prevalence study and hence the count of patients is only on confirmed results. But the check would then be to understand on whether on the confirmed results the various patient status has an effect on the occurrence of the disease.

Comment: @Dave, was just thinking, so based on the fact that this is prevalence related, is it even necessary to do statistical checks and the p values associated. there would indeed be situations in this study where is can be calculated i.e. where a i x j matrix present itself. but i am just interested on a case where there is a 1 x j matrix.